# Query Transactional Replication Article Filters

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

Through the UI, I can see that I have 2 tables with filters on them. I need to be able to query this information but cannot find the table that contains the data. I did a search for any column in the Distribution database with a name like either "Filter" or "Where". The results are below. Unfortunately, none of these tables has the data I'm looking for  in them.

```
 - SELECT * FROM IHarticles 
 - SELECT * FROM IHextendedArticleView 
 - SELECT * FROM MSarticles 
 - SELECT * FROM MSmerge_articlehistory 
 - SELECT * FROM MSmerge_articleresolver 
 - SELECT * FROM sysarticlecolumns 
 - SELECT * FROM sysarticles
 - SELECT * FROM sysextendedarticlesview
 - SELECT * FROM sysschemaarticles
```

Does anyone know where this data is held?

Comment: sysarticles does have 2 columns filter and filter_clause in distribution database. I have checked it on SQL Server 2012. What version are you on?

Comment: Thanks, I am using 2012 SP3 CU2 Enterprise; however, the values in the Filter and Filter_Clause fields in that table are all NULL.

Comment: Are you sure filter is applied correctly on replication articles? If it is then it should definitely be present in sysarticles.

Comment: Sadly yes...we have 3 filters in place and that was one of the first things I checked. I was very surprised to find the fields empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To research this, I configured transactional replication on my test server with 1 article having row filter. I did this for Adventureworks.Sales.Store table having [CustomerID] <10. Initially, I tried querying distribution..sysarticles to check the filter details. But, surprisingly it did not show any data in it.

Then I checked Adventureworks..sysarticles(i.e. in publication database) and that did the trick. See the below result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I believe that is where I must have been looking as well. This helps a lot!

Comment: Thanks for this helpful trick!